# Cannot create workspace in ibm worklight

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

After creating a project in eclipse with ibm worklight an error pops up saying "PROBLEM CREATING WORKSPACE" and when i exit eclipse it says problem occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be useful if you'll add the log from the Problems and/or Errors view in Eclipse. It sounds like an Eclipse problem.

Suggestion: use a fresh workspace and then provide the logs if it happens still. It should not.
Eclipse > File > Workspace...

Comment: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Worklight Project Builder' on project 'YummyjQueryMobileProject'.
Failed to cleanup temp classes folder
Failed to cleanup temp classes folder
Failed to cleanup temp classes folder
Failed to cleanup temp classes folder

Comment: @RishavBasuMullick, It mentions jQuery Mobile. Are you trying to add jQuery Mobile to your app? Which version of it? What is your Worklight version?

Comment: This does not answer my question. What is your Worklight version. What is the jQuery Mobile version. Close Eclipse, open the TMP folder and delete the wlBuildResources folder. This still sounds like an Eclipse/system issue and not Worklight.

Comment: No repository found at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/. this error was given when i changed the drive and tried to install it.

Comment: Get a new eclipse and go to help->eclipse market place. Search for "mobilefirst platform".

Comment: sorry for the delay but i opened the eclipse as run as administrator and it worked perfectly.

Comment: i just need another help. Code to shift the google map to a particular city when the city is selected from drop down list? i am doing this in eclipse with ibm worklight. plzzz help.